# how to flag rows on different conditions in R

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
   ID      Name1     Name2      Name3     Name4    Name5
   1       abc       NA         der       def      NA
   2       NA        NA         NA        NA       NA
   3       abc       def        rtg       der      ret
   4       rty       NA         NA        NA       NA
```

I want to flag the rows based on the condition that, if all the values are present in all the columns then it should be flaged as `Yes`,if all are NA's then it should flag `NO` and if any one value is present then it should flag it `Partial`

My desired dataframe would be

```
  ID      Name1     Name2      Name3     Name4    Name5   Flag
   1       abc       NA         der       def      NA     Partial
   2       NA        NA         NA        NA       NA     No
   3       abc       def        rtg       der      ret    Yes
   4       rty       NA         NA        NA       NA     Partial
```

How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$flag <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df)) == dim(df)[2] - 1, "NO", ifelse(rowSums(!is.na(df)) == dim(df)[2], "YES", "Partial"))

 ID Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5    flag
1  1   abc  <NA>   der   def  <NA> Partial
2  2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      NO
3  3   abc   def   rtg   der   ret     YES
4  4   rty  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> Partial
```

Comment: you can use `cut(rowSums(is.na(dat[-1])),c(-1,0,4,5),c("NO","partial","Yes"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by counting the rowWise na values and subsequently chaining 2 if_else statements:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(NA_counter = rowSums(is.na(df))) %>%
  mutate(Flag = if_else(NA_counter == 5, "No", 
                    if_else(NA_counter > 0, "Partial", "Yes")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
d <- read.table(text = "ID      Name1     Name2      Name3     Name4    Name5
   1       abc       NA         der       def      NA
                2       NA        NA         NA        NA       NA
                3       abc       def        rtg       der      ret
                4       rty       NA         NA        NA       NA",
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

d$Flag <- apply(d[ , grepl("Name", colnames(d))], 1, 
                function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), "No",
                                   ifelse(any(is.na(x)), "Yes", "Partial") ))
d
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` solution using `dplyr::case_when`

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        NA_count = apply(., 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))),
        Flag = case_when(
            NA_count == 0 ~ "Yes",
            NA_count < ncol(df) - 1 ~ "Partial",
            TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
    select(-NA_count)
#  ID Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5    Flag
#1  1   abc  <NA>   der   def  <NA> Partial
#2  2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      No
#3  3   abc   def   rtg   der   ret     Yes
#4  4   rty  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> Partial
```

Answer (score 0):

The explicit non elegant way ... using dplyr and assuming columns are characters

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(flag= ifelse(is.na(Name1) | is.na(Name2) | is.na(Name3) | 
                      is.na(Name4) | is.na(Name5), "Partial", "Yes" )) %>%
  mutate(flag= ifelse(is.na(Name1) & is.na(Name2) & is.na(Name3) & 
                      is.na(Name4) & is.na(Name5), "No", flag))
```